# C# Client/Server: using Streamreader/writer

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, streamreader, streamwriter

I'm relatively new to C# but here goes:

I am developing a remote file service client/server console application in C# which is supposed to exchange messages using synchronous sockets.

One of the main problems (even thought it might seem simple) is to return a string from the server, to the client using streamreader/streamwriter.

The application user a command line interface with options (from a switch statement) to execute actions. I.e. typing 1 and enter would execute the code to send the string from the server to the client.

Below is a sample code from the client:

```
        try
        {
            using (TcpClient client = (TcpClient)clientObject)
            using (NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream())
            using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(stream))
            using (StreamWriter wr = new StreamWriter(stream))
            {

                string menuOption = rd.ReadLine();


                switch (menuOption)
                    {
                        case "1":
                        case "one":
                            string passToClient = "Test Message!";
                            wr.WriteLine(passToClient);
                            break;
                   } 
                      while (menuOption != "4");
               }
         }
```

I understand the code I posted is just a snippet of the program, but it would take up a fair amount of space and was hoping you can gather what I mean from this, if not I will post more.

This is just to give a general idea of what I am going for,

I appreciate any help / advice you can give. Its not so much code examples I'm looking for (although a little would help) but more some explanation on streamreader/writer as I cant seem to understand much of what is online.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're just missing a `wr.flush();` but this article should cover everything you need:

http://thuruinhttp.wordpress.com/2012/01/07/simple-clientserver-in-c/

Comment: Ah, I missed `Flush()`.

Answer (score 4):

Whenever you use `StreamWriter` you need to [Flush()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.flush(v=vs.110).aspx) the contents of the stream. I'll quote MSDN as the reason becomes quite clear:

> Clears all buffers for the current writer and causes any buffered data to be written to the underlying stream.

You can call it quite simply like:

```
wr.flush();
```

Answer (score 3):

Solution can be simpler:

```
StreamWriter wr = new StreamWriter(stream) { AutoFlush = true }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran a test using your code, and it works fine, I can step right into the "one" case statement.

I am guessing you are either not including the line-break in the string you are sending, or you just have the TcpClient or TcpListener configured wrong.

Here is the Client-Side code for my test:

```
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 13579);
        string message = "one" + Environment.NewLine;
        Byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
        NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
```

Here is the Server-Side:

```
        IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
        TcpListener server = new TcpListener(localAddr, 13579);
        server.Start();

        TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
        using (client)
        using (NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream())
        using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(stream))
        using (StreamWriter wr = new StreamWriter(stream))
        {
            string menuOption = rd.ReadLine();
            switch (menuOption)
            {
                case "1":
                case "one":
                    string passToClient = "Test Message!";
                    wr.WriteLine(passToClient);
                    break;
            }
            while (menuOption != "4") ;
        }
```

Just run the server-side code first, which will block while waiting for connection and then while waiting for data. Then run the client-side code. You should be able to catch a breakpoint on the switch().