# StreamWriter doesn't write to network stream, but StreamReader can read succesfully in C#?

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, client-server

This is my code at the moment:

```
        static IPAddress ipAddr = IPAddress.Parse("MYIPADRESSGOESHERE");
        static IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddr, 88);
        static Socket Server = new Socket(ipAddr.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Server.Bind(localEndPoint);
            Server.Listen(10);
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Ready");
                Socket clientSocket = Server.Accept();
                NetworkStream networkStream = new NetworkStream(clientSocket);
                StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(networkStream);
                StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(networkStream);
                string line = streamReader.ReadLine();
                while (line != "STOP")
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("Client says: " + line);
                    switch (line)
                    {
                        case "START":
                            streamWriter.WriteLine("WELCOME");
                            Console.WriteLine("here");
                            break;
                        case "DATA":

                            break;
                    }
                    line = streamReader.ReadLine();
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Client disconnected");
            }
        }
```

I'm using telnet as the client. The connection is established correctly. Sending anything from telnet echoes "Client says: " on the server console. Sending "STOP" disconnects the server. However, when I send "START", I can see "here" on the server console, but I do not get a response on the client console (telnet).

My assumption is there is something wrong with StreamWriter, either in the declaration or in the calling of the WriteLine method. I am not sure how to fix this.

Comment: Looks like this is a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22675704/c-sharp-client-server-using-streamreader-writer

You are missing a call to flush the stream after writing to it.

Comment: @EricMagers I added streamWriter.Flush(); Right before the streamWriter.WriteLine("WELCOME"); line. This resulted in "WELCOME" being sent to the client, but only after I send "START" the second time. The first "START" results in no response? Only the second and all consequent "START" commands issue a response.

Comment: The Flush should happen after the writeline, not before. I think what you're seeing is the previous iterations message being sent with every flush call (which is why the first iteration doesn't appear to have any output)

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. It fixed the problem. Thank you!